# Madurai to Germany via Dubai - SpiceJet

Tags: schengen, transit, indian-citizens, dubai, spicejet

I am an Indian citizen with a German residency permit. I am travelling from Germany to Dubai by Pegasus Airlines and then from Dubai to Madurai by SpiceJet separately, in both directions. I need to transfer myself in Dubai. I have found that transit is possible in Dubai airport via transit desk without UAE transit visa.

But, I have read on SpiceJet's website that Indian citizens travelling from India to Dubai need "Ok to Go" stamp in their passports. It is not clearly explained for transit people like me with Schengen visa.

Q1:
Will SpiceJet in Madurai check "Ok to Go" and reject me (Indian citizen with Schengen residence permit) in Madurai airport during my return journey?

If yes; Q2:
Is there is any other possibility to solve the above problem?

If "Ok to Go" is ultimately needed for SpiceJet in Madurai; Q3:
How can I get it from Germany and how much does it cost?

Comment: `I have found that transit is possible in Dubai airport via transit desk without UAE transit visa.` - be careful, if you have checked luggage this is not possible.

Comment: @pnuts: I have talked with spicejet. "Ok to Go" is a kind of approval provided to PNR ticket number with connection to UAE visa. It is not needed for transit people.

Comment: @Burhan: Really? I have heard that if we pay some money, transit desk will help to get the checked in luggage. Is it false? Do you have onsite experience on it?

Comment: The last time I had to transit through Dubai (4 months ago), there was no such option. I will be flying through Dubai in a few days and I will confirm again for you.

Comment: @Burhan: Fantastic. I have heard that it is possible if transit is within same Terminal. If it is between different terminal, it is not possible. Please enquire the possibilities for me. I will travel on 15 Nov :).

Comment: There are three terminals at the airport, and you don't need a visa to transit between any of them. If you have bags _that are not checked through_, then you need to collect your bags; and your onward boarding pass.

Comment: Yaa.. Yaa.. I understand it :). I heard the possibility of transferring checked in luggage through transfer desk (if it is in same Terminal). But, I am not sure about it. If you know about it, it would be thankful. I know that I don't need transit visa. I mentioned it in my post :)

Comment: Okay, so I just got back from Dubai and according to the transfer desk, they are not authorized to collect and re-check in luggage on behalf of passengers.

There is no fee for this service; because this service does not exist. Your bags will be offloaded in Dubai, because the tag on your baggage will have DXB as the final destination.

If you do not have checked-in baggage, and you do not have an onward boarding pass, you can get one issued at the transit desk.

You will find the transit desk immediately after the first set of stairs you descend.

Comment: Great Burhan... Thanks lot for your information. So, I try to avoid my checkedin baggage :).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid want to turn that into an answer? I've bountied.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Dubai there is no airside transit visa.

However there is no provision to collect checked-in luggage without going through immigration procedures.

Practically, this means that if you have two single journeys (ie, two tickets on two different carriers not on codeshare) and you have checked your bags - you need to be able to enter Dubai to collect your bags.

The transit desk can only assist with boarding passes (and in case your in-bound flight is delayed, they can arrange to get you a seat on the next flight to your destination).

There are three lounge services at Dubai airports. [Marhaba](http://www.marhabaservices.com/english/), [Ahlan](http://www.ahlan-dia.com/Services.aspx?Id=1) and the premium [Al Majlis](http://www.dubaiairports.ae/while-you-are-here/services-facilities/meet-greet). All provide baggage assistance of some sort, <strike>but none are available for transit passengers.</strike>

Marhaba offers [transit baggage retag service](http://www.marhabaservices.com/english/our-services/meet-greet) (for a fee, and subject to airline regulations).

Comment: Marhaba offer baggage collection+recheck for transit passengers, for a fee - see [Meet and Greet Services](http://www.marhabaservices.com/english/our-services/meet-greet) then click the *Transfer* tab for details