# Collecting baggage in different countries through different airlines

Tags: air-travel, transit, luggage, new-york-city, dubai

Long story short..I am flying from New York to Dubai with Delta and Dubai to Mumbai with Air India.

How do I obtain my baggage and recheck the baggage with Air India without having to go through customs? I am not planning on obtaining UAE visa..

Comment: Almost-duplicate (airlines different): [Madurai to Germany via Dubai - SpiceJet](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/38241/26)

Comment: Seems the answer is in that other question since the airlines don't really matter. You will either need to be able to enter the UAE or use some type of baggage transfer service as suggested in question linked.

Comment: If you have a single booking / ticket, then Delta should check your baggage to your final destination, as they have ticket interline agreements with Air India.  If you have two separate bookings / tickets, then call Delta and ask if they will check your bags through.  If they will not then you have to get a visa or use the services outlined in the question linked to in Gagravarr's comment.